# Microsoft Graph API: Getting the users who are assigned to an Enterprise application

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to pull list of Users for a given Enterprise Application from MS Graph?  I can see that Azure portal is making this query:

[https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/ManagedApplications/{enterprise-app-id}/AppRoleAssignments](https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/ManagedApplications/%7Benterprise-app-id%7D/AppRoleAssignments)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

> If the resource service principal is an application that has app roles
> granted to users and groups, this will return all the users and groups
> assigned app roles for this application.

You can use this api to list all users or groups assigned to the enterprise application:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo
```

You need to replace `{id}` with `Object ID`.

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)